# Getting meteor 0.9.2 build to work OSX -> Linux

Tags: linux, node.js, macos, meteor

I was using meteor 0.8.x but recently tried to upgrade to 0.9.2. It works locally but I'm not having any luck with `meteor bundle` or `meteor build`

First I got this error

```
/var/projects/myproject/live/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:198
}).run();
   ^
Error: /var/projects/myproject/live/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build/Release/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at bindings (/var/projects/myproject/live/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:74:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/projects/myproject/live/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:1:97)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Things I've tried

- Made sure `live/bundle/programs/server/node_modules` does not exist before starting.
- ran `npm install` in `live/bundle/programs/server` as the README says to

Things I noticed. There's no `bcrypt` deps in `live/bundle/programs/server/package.json`. In 0.8.2 I had commands to install both `fibers` and `bcrypt` manually but apparently I don't need the fibers one anymore. It looks like I do need the `bcrypt` one but it's in a different location than it used to be.

I don't see anything in the docs about needing to go to `/var/projects/myproject/live/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt` and install `bcrypt`. I can manually delete it but am I doing something wrong?

Like I said I'm already installing it where 0.8.2 needed it in `programs/server`. Should I be manually installing in `program/server/npm/npm-bcrypt`? Should I add that to my list of places to ignore

I put that in just to try it and so now I get this error

```
/var/projects/myproject/live/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: Cannot find module 'websocket-driver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/projects/myproject/live/bundle/programs/server/npm/ddp/node_modules/faye-websocket/lib/faye/websocket.js:8:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Is that yet another module I need to manually install? I'm getting the impression I'm just doing something fundamentally wrong.

I've got the following meteor packages

.meteor/packages

```
# Meteor packages used by this project, one per line.
#
# 'meteor add' and 'meteor remove' will edit this file for you,
# but you can also edit it by hand.

standard-app-packages
audit-argument-checks
iron:router@0.9.3
meteorhacks:npm@1.2.0

npm-container
```

packages.json

```
{
  "semver": "2.3.1",
  "winston": "0.7.3",
  "winston-loggly": "1.0.1"
}
```

note: I'm developing/bundling on OSX but deploying on Ubuntu.

Comment: not using sass here by any chance?

Comment: no, no sass. In fact I'm not using much of anyhting. It's a small project. 1 Collection. So far only 10 entries. Updated question with

Comment: I have the same problem, please post answer if you come right.

Answer (score 7):

I had similar problems - I posted my solution over on DO

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-js-application-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-nginx?comment=19780

---

UPDATE - Here is the answer from that forum:

If anyone else has an issue like this with bcrypt - the app probably has its own copy in 
`/home/yourapp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/`

delete that noise. Then do this.

`cd /home/yourapp/bundle/programs/server`

`npm install bcrypt`

Then

`cp -r /home/yourapp/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/bcrypt /home/yourapp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/`

then start your app and enjoy the meteory goodness.

Comment: solved it for me. I don't understand why bcrypt wouldn't be included in the `package.json` by Meteor when building, so that a standard `npm install` when deploying automatically recompiles the package instead of moving a platform dependent .js file around.

Answer (score 0):

#### On the general problem of . . .

(for those stumbling here via Google)

> Cannot find module 'MODULE-NAME'

or

> Can't find npm module 'MODULE-NAME'

If you've recently added or removed packages while the application is running, try stopping and restarting your meteor application.

```
// stop ( "CTRL+C" in terminal that launched process )
$ kill `ps ax | grep '[m]eteor' | awk '{print $1}'`

// start
$ meteor
```