# Deploying Meteor app from OS X to Linux causes bcrypt issues

Tags: meteor

I have just deployed my first production Meteor app, but ran into a pretty significant issue.  When I tried to run my app, I get the following error:

```
/home/hiapp/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: /home/hiapp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build/Release/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at bindings (/home/hiapp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:74:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/hiapp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:1:97)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Through some research, it seems that the issue is that bcrypt is platform-specific, and because my development is on OS X 10.10, but my production server is on Ubuntu 14.04, there-in lies the problem.  My work around was to run `npm install bcrypt` from the programs/server folder, then copy that from `programs/server/node_modules/bcrypt` to `programs/server/npm`.  This seems like a lot of manual steps.

I am just about to re-deploy my app with some fixes, and I am worried that I am going to have to again perform the same steps.  Is there a better way to deploy a Meteor app where you do not run into this issue?  My procedure currently is:

1. Run `meteor build`
2. scp resulting tarball to my server (Digital Ocean)
3. explode the tarball in my app users home directory
4. ADDED STEPS: recompile bcrypt and copy the directory over as stated above

I am guessing the auto-refresh will be broken as the first time the server tries to load the new libraries it will explode in fiery glory.  Would it be better to simply clone the GIT repo on the server and do the build straight from there, or can I use `mup` or any other tools to help smoothen the deployment process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same issue - I switched to using Meteor Up (MUP) instead and the problem went away. Not to mention its a lot more straightforward!

I followed this tutorial on youtube - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLGdXtZMmiI which covers deploying using MUP to Digital Ocean.

MUP's github page specifically mentions that it handles binary NPM modules - https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up#binary-npm-module-support

Hope that's some help!

Comment: I thought I read somehwhere that mup did not work on OS X.  Is that just the server-side piece, or is that for the client as well?

Comment: This was EXACTLY what I needed!  MUP works flawlessly, did a better job of setting up the environment than I did, and allows me control from my desktop to tail logs and restart the server without having to login.

Comment: No, I use MUP, however, this problem still occurs

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways of getting around this time-consuming problem which are totally dependant on how you deploy.

## Manual deploy

If you are manually deploying your app then make sure that you are using node v0.10.36<sup>1</sup> and only that. Meteor does not work well with node v0.12.x. More specifically, the fibers module causes a lot of problems, it chokes on various errors<sup>2</sup>.

The following is the procedure that fixed it for me<sup>3, 4</sup>:

1. Remove the bcrypt module from the `npm` directory:

   ```
   $ cd path_to_your_app/bundle/programs/server
   $ rm -rf npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/
   ```
2. Install the bcrypt module into the `node_modules` directory first. This builds bcrypt against the server's OS:

   ```
   $ npm install bcrypt
   ```
3. Move the newly created bcrypt module into the `npm` directory:

   ```
   $ cp -r node_modules/bcrypt npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt
   ```
4. Finally, **restart** the app, mogodb and any web server processes such as nginx<sup>6</sup>, through upstart if you have it configured. Under the heading **sanity steps** below you can perform if the steps outlined above have not fixed it for you.

## Using Meteor Up (mup)

If you are using mup then the process is much easier as other answers on this thread point out. However, there are cases where errors still arise including the `invalid ELF header` error. Make sure you have the most recent version of mup `npm update mup -g`.

1. The first step is to remove any pre-existing app and nodejs package. Mup installs the app into `/opt/` and within there you can find `your_app` and `nodejs`. Remove them.
2. Verify that you have the correct node version, 0.10.36 only<sup>1</sup> and the following settings, in the `mup.json` file:

   ```
   {

    ...

     "setupMongo": true,
     "setupNode": true,
     "nodeVersion" : "0.10.36",
     "setupPhantom": true,
     "enableUploadProgressBar": true,

     // Application name (No spaces)
     "appName": "your_app",

     // Location of app (local directory)
     "app": ".",

    ...

   }
   ```
3. Run:

   ```
   $ mup setup
   $ mup deploy
   ```
4. Navigate to the `server` folder on your server and rebuild modules:

   ```
   $ cd /opt/your_app/app/programs/server
   $ npm rebuild
   $ npm install
   ```

   Optional: `$ sudo npm update node-gyp -g`
5. Finally, **restart** the app, mogodb and any web server processes such as nginx<sup>6</sup>. After the above steps, you may want to look at **sanity steps** below for more debugging options.

---

## Sanity steps

There are a few other steps you can perform:

- Note that apache may also bind itself to the same port that nginx is running on. Look at your app's error logs and your web server's error logs to see if there are any issues. Stop apache via `sudo service apache2 stop` or [brute force close](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9346231/3526705) (not recommended) any running processes on port 80.

  - Then remove or move the apache2 conf file to prevent it from starting up again. All conf files are located in `/etc/init` or `/etc/init.d`.
- Use `$ mup logs -f` to view mup logs. To view errors from your app, the end of the file, `/var/log/upstart/your_app.log` is useful (assuming you have upstart configured).
- If using nginx make sure your directories are symlinked.

  ```
  $ ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/your_server_config /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/your_server_config
  ```

  Moreover, make sure that you have specified a `default_server`<sup>5</sup> in `your_server_config`.
- Check that mongodb can run.

---

### References

1. Meteor version 1.0.4.1 (released near the end of March 2015) requires that node version 0.10.36 be installed. I recommend using the node version manager, [n](https://github.com/tj/n), to control what version of node is running on your server at any one time. [Link](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/issues/349).
2. The dreaded `[XXX.XX.XXX.XX] Error: '/opt/your_app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-v8-3.28/fibers.node' is missing. Try reinstalling 'node-fibers'?` error. [Link](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/issues/332).
3. The procedure is modified from here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26173194/3526705).
4. For your information, I used DigitalOcean's very helpful guide on deploying a meteor app to a server. [Link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-js-application-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-nginx).
5. Specifying a `default_server`. [Link](http://blog.gahooa.com/2013/08/21/nginx-how-to-specify-a-default-server/).
6. Common processes to restart are: `sudo service mongod/nginx/yourapp restart`.

Comment: Thank You! Your Answer is amazing and saved me a whole day! Manual steps are working for me with Meteor 1.2 under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, nvm and nodejs 0.10.40. I finally launched my Meteor app!

Answer (score 0):

Running `npm rebuild` at `bundle/programs/server/npm/` should take care of rebuilding the modules for the server platform, regardless of the original app being bundled at Linux or MacOS.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and did the following to fix it:

- **Uninstall nodejs**

  `sudo apt-get remove nodejs`
- **Remove any remaining files**

  `rm -rf ~/.nvm ~/.npm`

  `sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/node /opt/nodejs /usr/lib/node_modules /usr/local/lib/node_modules`
- **Upgrade node version from the default setting in mup.json**

  `"nodeVersion": "0.10.33",`
- **Run mup setup and deploy**

  `mup setup`

  `mup deploy`