# Error while deploying Meteor application using mup deploy

Tags: mongodb, deployment, meteor, server, digital-ocean

I'm deploying Meteor application to Digital Ocean and MongoDB to Compose.io, but get error every time. This is my first time deploying to digital ocean and compose.io, so I'm totally confused. Anybody has a suggestion what should I do ?

```js
[45.55.144.173] ✘ Invoking deployment process: FAILED

-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
p ERR! cwd /opt/comicsprout/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
child_process: customFds option is deprecated, use stdio instead.
../src/coroutine.cc: In function ‘void* find_thread_id_key(void*)’:
../src/coroutine.cc:90:3: warning: ‘thread_id’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   if (tls == thread_id) {
   ^
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
Latest deployment failed! Reverted back to the previous version.
-----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
rget) Release/obj.target/fibers.node: Finished
COPY Release/fibers.node
make: Leaving directory /opt/comicsprout/tmp/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/build' Installed in/opt/comicsprout/tmp/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-v8-3.28/fibers.node`
underscore@1.5.2 node_modules/underscore

eachline@2.3.3 node_modules/eachline
└── type-of@2.0.1

chalk@0.5.1 node_modules/chalk
├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.3
├── ansi-styles@1.1.0
├── supports-color@0.2.0
├── has-ansi@0.1.0 (ansi-regex@0.2.1)
└── strip-ansi@0.3.0 (ansi-regex@0.2.1)

semver@4.1.0 node_modules/semver

source-map-support@0.2.8 node_modules/source-map-support
└── source-map@0.1.32 (amdefine@0.1.0)

fibers@1.0.5 node_modules/fibers
Waiting for MongoDB to initialize. (5 minutes)
connected
comicsprout stop/waiting
comicsprout start/running, process 12827
Waiting for 30 seconds while app is booting up
Checking is app booted or not?
comicsprout stop/waiting
comicsprout start/running, process 12930
```

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error some time ago, see [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31291860/3526705) for a much more detailed answer. It's an issue to do with bcrypt and I found that the issue is more prevalent on DigitalOcean servers.

To sum up:

1. Mup installs the app into `/opt/` and within there you can find `your_app` and `nodejs`. Remove them.
2. Verify that you have the correct node version, 0.10.36 only and the following settings, in the `mup.json` file:

   ```
   {

    ...

     "setupMongo": true,
     "setupNode": true,
     "nodeVersion" : "0.10.36",
     "setupPhantom": true,
     "enableUploadProgressBar": true,

     // Application name (No spaces)
     "appName": "your_app",

     // Location of app (local directory)
     "app": ".",

    ...

   }
   ```
3. Run:

   ```
   $ mup setup
   $ mup deploy
   ```
4. Navigate to the `server` folder on your server and rebuild modules:

   ```
   $ cd /opt/your_app/app/programs/server
   $ npm rebuild
   $ npm install
   ```

   Optional: `$ sudo npm update node-gyp -g`
5. Finally, **restart** the app, mogodb and any web server processes such as nginx.