# bundle of meteor build not responding

Tags: node.js, meteor, build, bundle

Tried to use meteor build to build node bundle. However, when I did `node main.js` the terminal didn't print out anything. My meteor version is 1.0.3.1. Detailed steps are listed below.

```
~/misc$ meteor create foo
foo: created.     

To run your new app:                          
  cd foo                                      
  meteor

~/misc$ cd foo/
~/misc/foo$ meteor build ~/misc/meteor_build2/ --directory
~/misc/foo$ cd ../meteor_build2
~/misc/meteor_build2$ cd bundle/programs/server/
~/misc/meteor_build2/bundle/programs/server$ npm install
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data

> fibers@1.0.1 install /home/chihchengliang/misc/meteor_build2/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
> node ./build.js

`linux-x64-v8-3.14` exists; testing
Binary is fine; exiting
underscore@1.5.2 node_modules/underscore

semver@4.1.0 node_modules/semver

fibers@1.0.1 node_modules/fibers

eachline@2.3.3 node_modules/eachline
└── type-of@2.0.1

source-map-support@0.2.8 node_modules/source-map-support
└── source-map@0.1.32 (amdefine@0.1.0)

chalk@0.5.1 node_modules/chalk
├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.2
├── ansi-styles@1.1.0
├── supports-color@0.2.0
├── strip-ansi@0.3.0 (ansi-regex@0.2.1)
└── has-ansi@0.1.0 (ansi-regex@0.2.1)

~/misc/meteor_build2/bundle/programs$ cd ..
~/misc/meteor_build2/bundle$ ROOT_URL=http://example.com/ node main.js
```

And then I got only a flashing pointer, no any other response.

Comment: take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903097/getting-meteor-0-9-2-build-to-work-osx-linux)

Comment: not working. I followed the steps to install bcrypt not working.

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: I've solved it. `ROOT_URL=http://localhost PORT=3000` the root url and the port MUST be separated. The terminal will print nothing but results could be seen on browser. Thanks for answering Ethaan.

Answer (score 0):

Run it with `ROOT_URL=http://localhost PORT=3000` as per @user2754799 comment above.

I had the same issue and almost did not check this question since it had no answers.